# Is it possible to increase the number of entries in the entry list in the entry view, where default is 100 per page?

Tags: craft3, control-panel, admin, craft.entries

Is it possible to increase the number of entries in the entry list in the entry view, where default is 100 per page? We want to show 300 entries per page in the admiun panel.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a native way to do it, and the workaround is pretty hacky.

See here for relevant discussion: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/discussions/8707