# How to increase control panel pagination item count?

Tags: craft3, control-panel, pagination

Our client whats to show 200 records in the control-panel entries list per page. Is it possible to change via any config settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been [asked before quite recently](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/38925/is-it-possible-to-increase-the-number-of-entries-in-the-entry-list-in-the-entry), and I don't believe there's been a better solution posted since then. Check out the answer on that post to see the solution, which involves using a bit of JavaScript and the Control Panel JS plugin to override the 100 entry limit.